# Are there any libraries that bring CS4 Actionscript to Flash CS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4, flash-cs3

Are there any custom libraries available that allow me to code/publish in CS3 using some of the features of CS4?

EDIT:

I say "some", because I understand that it is obviously nearly impossible to reimplememnt CS4 in CS3.

Comment: Do you mean AS3 to AS2 ? FP10 to FP9/FP8 ? Which methods are you looking for precisely ?

Comment: @Theo T. - Nope, CS4 to CS3. The 3D and bone tool methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between CS3 and CS4 in terms of code. You just need to target the current Flash Player 10 platform in your publish settings. They are both using the same Actionscript 3 libraries.

You can't load a CS4 project in CS3, but you can save your project to be CS3 compatible inside of flash CS4.

Oh, my bad. It's true CS3 can not compile for the Flash 10 platform. Therefore, no. There is no library, because the changes all require the new benefits of the Flash Player 10.

You can however use flex to compile your code. This will however require you to convert your code to flex.

Comment: there are differences in code, not huge ones generally but for example all the 3D elements, matrix and orientation classes are not in CS3 at all.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt be able to run anything in CS3 that is CS4 compliant only, mainly because it should require flash player 10 to run the code correctly, which you cant compile for in CS3.